# How do you callibrate ARToolKit with Google Glass

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-glass, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I've got a project using Google Glass and AR. My pick is using Unity 3D + ARToolKit (with optical see through) since it's free. My question is, how do you install and start the Google Glass camera callibration and optical callibration for ARToolKit?

Thanks.